# svn:ignore for subdirectories in subclipse/TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, subclipse, ignore

How do I ignore an entire subtree based on a directory pattern globally, without specifically excluding it for every project? For an example, I would like to exclude the target/ tree in all Maven projects without having to do so individually on a per-project basis.

Adding 'target' to Window > Preferences > Team > Ignored Resources works well, but will also exclude any target dir. elsewhere - which isn't a problem in my case, but I wanted to know if there is a better method to specify excluding certain dirs.

I have also added the exclusion pattern for Tortoise settings, and am aware of the subversion global-ignores property from trying to find the answer here just now :) Just an fyi that I do know **where** to put the pattern, but not sure of **what** it should be.

Comment: I don't understand: you first say that you want to exclude directories named 'target', and then you say you don't. So which one is it?

Comment: I do want to exclude the standard 'target' directory used for binaries in Maven .. but if potentially there are other 'target' dirs elsewhere in the source tree (there aren't in my case) I would be excluding those as well which I don't want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding ignore patterns, TortoiseSVN help says:

**You should not include path information in your pattern**. The pattern matching is intended for use against planes filenames and folder names. ... . If you want to ignore all tmp folders that exist within a prog folder and not within a doc folder you should use the svn:ignore. **There is no reliable way to achieve this using global ignore patterns**.

It seems your only option is svn:ignore property.

Comment: Thanks - I'll just have to ignore on a per-project basis using svn:ignore, was just being too lazy trying to use a global pattern ;)
Didn't think of checking this in TortoiseSVN help either, thank you for pointing me there as well!

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new Maven Project, remember to *svn:ignore* the *target* folder. That is the strongest way.

Ps : if you construct a pattern for *target*, you will match all word containing almost *target*...